# How to set holding torque in 3 phase stepper motor drivers?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have no previous experience with stepper motors. I want to use such a 3-phase driver in a 3-phase open loop stepper motor.
[image]

I looked at the datasheet here, but I couldn't see any information about holding torque.
http://leadshine.com/UploadFile/Down/3DM683m.pdf

What kind of signal should I send for holding torque in 3-phase stepper motor drivers? or in this type of driver, is the holding torque active when we make the pulse signal as logic 0?

Comment: Holding torque is a function of current so you are looking for ways to control the current.

Comment: yes i am reading the standstill thread now.

Comment: Sorry for not reading well, thanks.